# Adding a string to a string in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing various strings, and I want to be able to choose a particular element in the list, and concatenate it with a new string.

I thought this might do it:

```
checklist = [[0] + 'test' for [0] in checklist]
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `checklist[index] += 'test'` should work. Just make sure that you have the index you want to modify in the `index` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the string using its index and add the string to it using the `+` operator

```
checklist = ['a','b','c']
checklist[1] += 'd'
print checklist
#['a', 'bd', 'c']
```

Comment: Correct solution, but there is nothing to do with slice notation here so I'm not sure why you mention it.  This is just ordinary indexing, `list.__iadd__` to be precise.

Comment: @wim wooops, thanks for correcting me on that one :)

Answer (score 1):

The free variable in a list comprehension, i.e. the symbol between `for` and `in` in your code, must be a [valid python identifier](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).